# overly complex code problems

Tags: expect

So im trying to write a script that connects automatically via ssh

I have three files.
First is text file (file.txt) with my login credentials (now its only one but later there will be a few):

```
user1 abcd
```

Second file (connect.sh) is bash file that reads credentials and passes them to expect file Looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do 
    count=0; 
    words[0]="";  
    for word in $line; do 
        words[$count]="$word" 
        count=$(($count + 1)) 
    done 
    myDir="$(dirname "$0")" 
    "$myDir/find.sh" "${words[1]}" 
done < "$1"
```

The third file (find.sh) is /expect file which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set password [lindex $argv 0] 
spawn ssh "test@host.com" 
expect "Password:" 
send "$password\r" 
interact
```

However when I try to login it fails to deliver the password. As far as I checked the password is sent correctly to the expect script. Also I tried a set timeout function but it does not work either.

Comment: You should use SSH keys instead.

Comment: You are making this much harder for yourself. Expect is Tcl, a complete scripting system that can read files and doesn't have to call another process for help. Since your bash script is doing almost nothing (what's count for? you don't use it) drop the extra noise. Debugging `puts` in the expect script would help, too.

Comment: I am not sure if you made a typo while posting. Anyway, to simulate `enter` key, you have to use `\r`, not `/r`.

Answer (score 1):

As msw points out, you can do

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

proc main {passfile} {
    set fh [open $passfile r]
    while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
        lassign [split $line] user pass
        connect $user $pass
    }
    close $fh
}

proc connect {user password} {
    spawn ssh $user@host.com
    expect "Password:" 
    send "$password\r" 
    interact
}

main [lindex $argv 0]
```

Then invoke your expect script with the password file

```
./test.exp file.txt
```

BTW, ".sh" is not a great extension to use for an expect program.